# finding the parent element in context using jquery with a specific class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the parent element of the link when it has a specific class name to it.

I have the below list which I use as a navigation menu, I have the ul(subitem) inside li(has-subitem) closed(display:hidden) when I load the page. Now I would like to have one of it open depending on the page I am in.

For that I am trying to do this.

Whenever I have the link inside "subitem li" with class name "current" I would like to keep the "has-subitem" open instead of closing it. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/balasivagnanam/ymgpvh0n/) here

but it is not working somehow. I am new to JS :(

```
<ul class="navi-list">
    <li class="no-subitem"> <a class="current">Overview</a>
 <span class="navi-current"></span>

    </li>
    <li><a class="has-subitem"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fw"> </i> Policies & Procedures </a>

        <ul class="submenu">
            <!-- whenever I have this "current" i would like to find the li above with class "has-subitem" containing this link----> 
            <li><a class="current" href="#"> Documents & Resources </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> Upcoming Events </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> News </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> Announcements </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="has-subitem"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fw"> </i> Feeds & Discussions </a>

        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#"> Blog & Podcasts </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> Photos & Videos </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="has-subitem"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fw"> </i> About Us </a>

        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#"> FAQs </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> Contact Us </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore the `.has-subitem.current` element in the `submenu` hide command like

```js
$(".has-subitem:not(.current)").next(".submenu").hide();
$('.navi-list a.current').closest('li:has(> a.has-subitem)').children('.submenu').show();

$(document).on("click", ".has-subitem", function() {
  $(this).next(".submenu").slideToggle();
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass("fa-caret-right fa-caret-down");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navi-list">
  <li class="no-subitem">
    <a class="">Overview</a>
    <span class="navi-current"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="has-subitem"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fw"> </i> Policies & Procedures </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#" class="current"> Documents & Resources </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Upcoming Events </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> News </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Announcements </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="has-subitem"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fw"> </i> Feeds & Discussions </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#"> Blog & Podcasts </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Photos & Videos </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="has-subitem"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fw"> </i> About Us </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#"> FAQs </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Contact Us </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just noticed, the current class is at inner level as well. if you check code my question its has-subitem > .submenu > li >a.current , the above logic doesn't work :(

Comment: @BalaSivagnanam how can you have 2 current items?

Comment: can you check the updated fiddle, at one point it will be only one, but it can be either at .navi-list > li > a or at subitem > li > a

Comment: you are awesome :) suggest a good starter for learning javascript :)